# Trouble using the Haversine formula

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to use the Haversine formula to locate all bus stops within 1 mile of my current location. I have a MySQL DB table that contains the latitude/longitude locations of 5500 bus stops, and am using the following SQL query:

```
"SELECT id, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37.865971) ) * cos( radians( stopLat ) ) * cos( radians( stopLon ) - radians(-122.283775) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( stopLat ) ) ) ) 
AS distance FROM stops HAVING distance < 1 ORDER BY distance";`"
```

`stops` is the name of the DB table.

`stopLat` is the name of the column in which the latitudes are listed.

`stopLon` is the name of the column in which the longitudes are listed.

The lat/long of the location I'm using is 37.865971, -122.283775.

I'm doing this from a Java program. The program runs successfully, but my `ResultSet` comes 
back empty even though I am sure there are 50+ bus stops within a mile of the location being inputted.

Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT:** I've noticed that when I change `1` to anything over 500, it returns the entire result set. Further, it tells me that they are all between 497-480 miles away, which indicates the the problem is (as I suspected) in the math, i.e. in the statement itself.

**EDIT - SOLVED**  (see my own answer below)

Comment: The first step I would take is to take out HAVING distance < 1 and seeing what values it returns.

Comment: This is the haversine formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula Is what you're using a re-arrangement of it, or?

Comment: @Patashu - Yes, I'm using a slight rearrangement of it. Anyways, I got it working (see edit for how).

Comment: Instead of editing your question by adding the answer, remove it and post it as an answer, and "accept" the answer. Answering your own question is perfectly OK. Folks won't look for the answer to a question *in* the question, and your answer may help others.

Comment: @Bohemian - done. Will accept when I'm allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

This expression:

```
sin( radians(37) )
```

isn't precise enough. Changing it to:

```
sin( radians(37.865971) )
```

gives the expected result.